# Let $f : [a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function and let $c$ be a point of $(a, b)$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f : [a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function and let $c$ be a point of $(a, b)$.

$(i)$ If $f$ is monotonically (resp. strictly) increasing on $[a, c]$ and on $[c, b]$,
then show that $f$ is monotonically (resp. strictly) increasing on $[a, b]$.

$(ii)$ If $f$ is convex (resp. strictly convex) on $[a, c]$ and on $[c, b]$, then is it
true that $f$ is convex (resp. strictly convex) on $[a, b]$?

For the first one, is the proof very straightforward? Since I am not getting why the two interval has given two us?

The second one I am trying to prove but could not make an idea.

Comment: Try to draw a graph in $(ii)$ where the function is convex on each interval but not on their sum.

Answer (score 0):

The first part is automatic by definition. The second part is false; you can take for instance $[a,b]=[0,2]$, $c=1$ and define $f(x)=x^2$ on $[0,1]$ and $f(x)=(x-2)^2$ on $[1,2]$.

Comment: but your $f$ is changing. In question, the same $f$ is convex on both the intervals.

Comment: @JSN I don’t know what idea you have about what a function is, but there is no such thing as ‘varying function’ here.